# Construct a halide::runtime:buffer from halide::buffer

Tags: halide

In [lesson_10:AOT compilation part 2](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_10_aot_compilation_run.html), it said that "Halide::Runtime::Buffer also has constructors that wrap existing data instead of allocating new memory", but in the [docs](https://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_runtime_1_1_buffer.html) of halide::runtime::buffer, I can't find a constructor takes Buffer as its param, is it possible convert a halide::buffer to halide::runtime::buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`Halide::Buffer<T>::get()`](https://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_buffer.html#aad0071c898b8a4388caa93c30cf3f98b) method, which returns a `Halide::Runtime::Buffer<T>*`. This is a pointer to the underlying runtime buffer that the frontend buffer *wraps*. You should note the following:

> A Halide::Buffer is a named shared reference to a Halide::Runtime::Buffer.

Also, most methods of `Runtime::Buffer<T>` are available through `Buffer<T>` simply by using the `->` operator, which calls `get()` internally and is overloaded [here](https://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_buffer.html#a8c8bc5b953e984fd4f642dddb4a69a0e).